# AttributeError: module 'flax' has no attribute 'optim'

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, flax

My code is as follows:

```
!pip install flax
init_params = TransporterNets().init(key, init_img, init_text, init_pix)['params']
print(f'Model parameters: {n_params(init_params):,}')
optim = flax.optim.Adam(lr=1e-4).create(init_params)
```

However it shows the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'flax' has no attribute 'optim'
```

Even though I have seen documentation of `optim` attribute in `flax` module. How to fix it?

Comment: did you import it first ?  `import flax `

Comment: @mrCopiCat Yes, I have imported it. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can temporarily solve the issue by downgrading flax version from 0.6.0 to 0.5.1 at the moment.

```
pip install flax==0.5.1
```