# AttributeError: module 'flax' has no attribute 'nn'

Tags: python, jax, flax

I'm trying to run [RegNeRF](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/regnerf), which requires flax. On installing the latest version of flax==0.6.0, I got an error stating flax has no attribute optim. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73501131/3337089) suggested to downgrade flax to 0.5.1. On doing that, now I'm getting the error `AttributeError: module 'flax' has no attribute 'nn'`

I could not find any solutions on the web for this error. Any help is appreciated.

I'm using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `flax.optim` module has been moved to `optax` as of flax version 0.6.0; see [Upgrading my Codebase to Optax](https://flax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/optax_update_guide.html#replacing-flax-optim-with-optax) for information on how to migrate your code. If you're using external code that imports `flax.optim` and can't update these references, you'll have to install flax version 0.5.3 or older.

Regarding `flax.nn`: this module was replaced by `flax.linen` in flax version 0.4.0. See [Upgrading my Codebase to Linen](https://flax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/linen_upgrade_guide.html?highlight=flax.nn#upgrading-my-codebase-to-linen) for information on this migration. If you're using external code that imports `flax.nn` and can't update these references, you'll have to install flax version 0.3.6 or older.